# EditText within a RelativeLayout sticks on top of keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-relativelayout

I would like that my RelativeLayout containing my EditText and my ImageButton always remains sticky and full width on the top of the keyboard.

The keyboard always shows up when the Dialog is shown.

It should look like the YouTube app behavior when you submit a comment.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Add anonymous comment"
    android:textAppearance="@style/CodeFont" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/submit_comment"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/send_red" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
DialogComment dialogComment = new DialogComment(mainActivity, WPPostDataView.this);

            dialogComment.show();

            //Grab the window of the dialog, and change the width
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

            Window window = dialogComment.getWindow();
            lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
            //This makes the dialog take up the full width
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            window.setAttributes(lp);
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // request keyboard
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_w`enter code here`idth="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.ChatActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_chat">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

<EditText android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

<Button android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's almost perfect. I'd just need the white section above the LinearLayout to be transparent black (like a dialog empty space)

Comment: create a linearLayout above that

Comment: Could you give me more details please ?